# TTF/OTF file types in embedded software?

Tags: c++, unicode, embedded

I'm trying to use Unicode in my embedded application. From the Unifoundry.com website I've downloaded the latest Unicode TTF file. Is it possible to implement a Truetype font or open type font into my C++ code? And how should I get started with the missing libraries? Any advice or hints are welcome!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Possible? Absolutely. How you go about it - depends a lot on what resources you have already in your embedded system (it would be relatively easy in a X-Windows on Linux, it would potentially be rather hard on a small home-made OS)

Comment: Currently I'm using FreeRTOS as an Operating system on my embedded system. I don't want to install any form of Windows or Linux on this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render unicode characters using a TTF font, you probably want to check http://www.freetype.org/

But be noted that with freetype, you get a 'bitmap' of the characters, and still need some library to actually render it to screen.

An alternative is to use https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/ which depends on SDL.

Comment: This SDL_ttf seems to be a good solution for my question. Although the complete SDL seems to be a bit of an overkill as I don't need any support for controllers, mice, keyboards etc.. Funny thing is that when I open the readme file that is included in the SDL_ttf folder, it notes that the "SDL_ttf library is a wrapper around the excellent FreeType 2.0 library" any suggestions on how to interpret this in a practical way?